# Flask Running Issue: socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, flask, sublimetext3, flask-login

I got this error message [sublime issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki5xK.png)(`My OS: Ubuntu 16.04`) `"socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"` If I run flask in sublime text or PyCharm. But if I run flask on my Ubuntu [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TCuT.png),it is running. I understood that port used another service. Then i was trying to solve this issue from google/stackoverflow.

> `# ps ax | grep 5000     // or # ps ax | grep name_of_service`

```
# kill 3750            // or # killall name_of_service
```

But nothing changed. Only i found this problem when i was trying to run on sublime or pycharm IDE.

Comment: sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8000`

Answer (score 6):

Simple way is to use fuser.

```
fuser <yourport>/tcp #this will fetch the process/service
```

Replace `<yourport>` with the port you want to use

```
#to kill the process using <yourport> add `-k` argument 
fuser <yourport>/tcp -k
```

In your case

```
fuser 5000/tcp -k
```

Now you can run flask with that port.

Comment: Second line is not very clear, please add more content to your comments and description

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm allows you to edit the run configuration, so enter the configuration and check the box (top-right corner) saying: "singleton instance". In this way, every time you restart the server, the previous connection on port 5000 is closed and opened again.

Comment: How can i closed that port connection? Could you please tell me details.

Comment: Find out the process using that port and kill it, instead of ps, use the command "sudo lsof -i:5000" (I'm sorry for the bad formatting but I'm from mobile)

Comment: Yes. When i killed the process, it worked fine. But it was boring. I want to automatic kill that process and restart server. Is it possible?

Comment: If you're using PyCharm that's possible. Just kill the process before starting the Python app from PyCharm, then go to the project settings and set the "singleton instance" property (Google how to do it). After that, you're ready to go since PyCharm will automaticall kill the process and restart it if you press the "restart" button

Comment: I dont get helpful resource. I added this code  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=12345, use_reloader=True), It worked correctly in sublime text, when I re-saved again that file. But nothing happen in pycharm.

Comment: In PyCharm, to allow only one instance to run, go tu "Run" in the top bar, then "Edit Configurations...". Finally, check "Single instance only" at the right side.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. Now i will be testing.

Comment: Glad it helped out :)